# Cannot Implicitly Convert Type issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Code:

```
public class MtApsApprovalStatusDomainInput
{
   public List<MSExtended<UStatus>> UStatus { get; set; }
}

public class UStatus : StatusBase<UStatusValues>
{
}

public class MSExtended<T> : MSBase<T>
{
    public bool IsRecent { get; set; }
}
```

Error is throwing in the following line:

```
UStatus recentUStatus = MtApsStatusDomainInput.UStatus.Where(x => x.IsRecent).FirstOrDefault();
```

Error Details:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'Dt.Models.MtAps.MSExtended'
>   to 'Dt.Models.UStatus'

Comment: Please try to formulate a real question.

Comment: The error is absolutely correct, you need to show more code how you use `T` in `MSExtended`

Answer (score 0):

You wrapped `UStatus` into `MSExtended`, means

```
MtApsStatusDomainInput.UStatus.Where(x => x.IsRecent).FirstOrDefault();
```

will return `MSExtended<UStatus>` instead of `UStatus`.

Comment: You can extended MSExtend with public T Content { get; set; } than you can access it.

Answer (score 0):

`MtApsStatusDomainInput.UStatus.Where(x => x.IsRecent).FirstOrDefault()` will return 
`MSExtended<UStatus>` as its a list of `MSExtended<UStatus>`

you may want to use

```
MSExtended<UStatus> recentUStatus = MtApsStatusDomainInput.UStatus.Where(x => x.IsRecent).FirstOrDefault();
```

OR

```
var recentUStatus = MtApsStatusDomainInput.UStatus.Where(x => x.IsRecent).FirstOrDefault();
```